# Is the VBA "if" statement capable of producing different results based on the current cell selection?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is intended to select the entire column in a sheet if the header has a particular value. After that section of the macro runs. I want to check to see what part of the spreadsheet is highlighted and move from there using an IF statement. If the selection is a single cell (in this case A2) then the macro should go down one path. If the selection is an entire column, then it should go down a different path. Currently it is only finding the first part of the if select. In the case of the code below it is returning   MsgBox " The " & xStr & " column has not been found." regardless of what the current selection is.

I have attempted using the <>, is, and isnot parameters on Active.range.select but that is where my current knowledge ends. I am a beginner at VBA and have been cobbling this code together using a ton of trial an error/ online help.

```
Sub Testingifthen()
'
' Testingifthen Macro
'

 Range("A2").Select
  numRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRgUni As Range
Dim xFirstAddress As String
Dim xStr As String

    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = "Zip Code"
    Set xRg = Range("A2:CD2").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = Range("A2:CD2").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni = xRg
            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If
    xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select

    If Active.Range.Select <> Range("A2") Then

   MsgBox " The " & xStr & " column has not been found."

    Else

   MsgBox " The " & xStr & " column has been found."

   End If


'
End Sub
```

Comment: Try if Selection.Cells.Count >1 then...

Comment: First, get rid of `On Error Resume Next`. That is eating any runtime error, and should be avoided (except for very limited scope, and only then when you know what you're doing with it and how to trap it).

Comment: `Active.Range.Select` is totally not valid. `Active` is not a *thing*. It's not a variable and it's not a built-in/global object or method. Your error handler was likely swallowing that, with predictably (unexpected/undesired) results.

Comment: You will always get column not found because you are selecting an entire column just before that and then are looking to see if the selection is a single cell. (After you fix the code to not throw errors.)

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. This will enforce variable declaration, and raise a compile error against any variables which you may not have defined. Otherwise, these variables, if not assigned a value, will return an empty variant.

Comment: You will always get column not found because `Select` returns a boolean value, so unless your A2 cell contains *that* value, (you're implicitly comparing agsint the `.Value` property), it will never match.

Comment: The suggestion by Jonathan works for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim searchstr As String
    Dim searchrange As Range

    Set searchrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:CD2") 'headers

    searchstr = "Zip Code"

    If Not searchrange.Find(what:=searchstr) Is Nothing Then 'check if address is found
        MsgBox (searchstr & " Column Found")
    Else
        MsgBox (searchstr & " Column Not Found")
    End If
```